# how to Change Codeigniter pagination query string

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I want to change CodeIgniter pagination query string. When I use query string it will run & the url is good but data remaining same, without query string it will run properly.

My URL look like

```
example.com/1
```

But I want it to be like

```
example.com?page=1
```

Here is my controller code..

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = base_url().'/purchase/index';
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('purchase');
$config['per_page'] = 10;
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
$config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$page =($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

$data['pur_list'] = $this->purchase_model->purchase_list($config['per_page'],$page);
```

Comment: explain what's the issue. Not what you want remove it. Just explain whats the issue with the relevent image

Comment: My URL look like http://example.com/1 but i want http://example.com?page=1

Comment: add in your question please

Comment: check this https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html#customizing-the-pagination

Comment: when i set $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE; the $this->uri->segment(3) return null

Comment: try 4 `$this->uri->segment(4)`

Comment: already did it,but still same problem.

Answer (score 3):

this will give you output like

```
example.com?page=1&q=banana
```

```
$config = $this->config->item('pagination_config');
$config["base_url"] = base_url("search");
$config["total_rows"] = $this->SearchModel->getResultCount($query);
$config["per_page"] = 6;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;
$config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$current_page = $this->input->get('page',0);
$this->data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
$this->data['results'] = $this->SearchModel->getResults($query, $config["per_page"], $current_page);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index()
  {
    $config = [];
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "admin/subscribers";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->subscriber_model->count();
    $config["per_page"] = 10;
    $config['num_links'] = 9;
    $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
    $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
    $this->pagination->initialize( $config );
    $offset = ($this->input->get('page')) ? ( ( $this->input->get('page') - 1 ) * $config["per_page"] ) : 0;
    $data["results"] = $this->subscriber_model->get($config["per_page"], $offset );
    $data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;', $this->pagination->create_links() );
    $this->load->view("index", $data);
  }
```